# what does ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades do exactly in csporj (C# - Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

I added a package from Nuget that targeted .NET Standard 2.0

After that, I got build error below:

```
Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent     identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Xml.XDocument.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Xml.XDocument.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Threading.Timer.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Threading.Timer.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Threading.Tasks.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Threading.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Threading.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Text.Encoding.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Security.Principal.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Security.Principal.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Runtime.Handles.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Runtime.Handles.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.ObjectModel.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.ObjectModel.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Net.Requests.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Net.Requests.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Net.Primitives.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Net.Primitives.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Linq.Queryable.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Linq.Queryable.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Linq.Parallel.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Linq.Parallel.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Globalization.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Globalization.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.ComponentModel.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.ComponentModel.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Collections.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Collections.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Error   CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.
```

I found a solution and fixed it by adding  `<ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades> false </ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>` to .csproj file

My question is what is ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades and what does it do?

why is visual studio looking for libraries in "Reference Assemblies" folder? (isn't this for the design time?)

why are they put same libraries in another location ("Reference Assemblies")?

shouldn't visual studio load .Net libraries from "Windows" directory?

how is it possible to have different versions in different locations?

Sorry for a lot number of questions. I think they are not separate.